# Question about arc length.

Tags: calculus, integration, arithmetic

I am having some trouble finishing an arc length problem.

Specifically, what is $\int_{0}^{1}|x'(t)| dt=?$ Is it just $\int_{0}^{1} |x(t)| dt=|x(1)-x(0)|$? If so why?

Answer (score 1):

No. Imagine your particle oscillating on the way from $x(0)$ to $x(1).$ Then the integral is the total distance it covers, which could be way bigger than the RHS.

Comment: Is there a way to formally show that $\int_{0}^{1}|x'(t)|\geq|x(1)-x(0)|$?

Comment: Yes, there is, The magic words are "triangle inequality".

Comment: ok, $\int_{0}^{1}|x'(t)|dt\geq|\int_{0}^{1}x'(t)|=|x(1)-x(0)|dt$

Comment: Yup, that's correct (what you are using is an "infinite" version of triangle inequality).

Answer (score 1):

No.

$$\int_a^b{\left|f^{'}(t)\,dt\right|} = \left|f(b)\right| - \left|f(a)\right| \leq \left|f(b) - f(a)\right|$$

Why? Because of the triangle equality:

$$|a\, – b| \geq |a|\, – |b|$$